# How to add list of vector to list of data.frame objects as new slot by parallel?

Tags: r, list, dataframe

I have list of vector with different dimension and list of different data.frame objects respectively. I want to add vec.list to df.list by parallel as new attributes. How can I make this happen in fastest way? Thanks in advance

## toy data

```
df.list <- list(
  d1 <- data.frame(
    V1=seq(1, by=2, len=6), V2=seq(6, by=2, len=6),
    V3=letters[seq(1:6)], V4=sample(1:10, 6, replace = FALSE)),
  d2 <- data.frame(
    V1=seq(2, by=3, len=8), V2=seq(6, by=3, len=8),
    V3=letters[seq(1:8)], V4=sample(1:10, 8, replace = FALSE)),
  d3 <- data.frame(
    V1=seq(4, by=3, len=5), V2=seq(9, by=3, len=5),
    V3=letters[seq(1:5)], V4=sample(1:8, 5, replace = FALSE))
)
```

## the vector I want to add them by parallel:

```
vec.list <- list(sc1 <- c(1,3,5,6,7,8), 
                 sc2 <- c(2,4,5,7,9,10,14,16), 
                 sc3 <- c(6,10,11,13,15))
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)

df.list.new <- map2(.x = df.list , 
                    .y = vec.list , 
                    .f = function(x, y) bind_cols(x, data.frame('sc' = y)))
```

Comment: Thank you very much. Your solution is very efficient.

Comment: My pleasure. The real credit goes to the purrr package - thanks @hadley.

Answer (score 2):

Using base functions,

```
df.list.new = Map(cbind, df.list, sc = vec.list)
```

Unfortunately, this doesn't preserve your list names. But they can be reassigned

```
names(df.list.new) = names(df.list)
```

Comment: That's alright, but results is very satisfactory for me. Thanks for your help. If you don't mind, I have accepted Alex' answer. Cheers

Comment: Not at all! I prefer Alex's answer as well. It's just good to have options - in some cases using extra packages is undesirable.