# Iterate over dplyr code using purrr::map2

Tags: r, dplyr, purrr

I am relatively new to R, so my apologies if this question is too basic.

I have transactions that show quantity sold and revenue earned from different products. Because there are three products, there are `2^3 = 8` combinations for selling these products in a "basket." Each basket could be sold in any of the three given years (2016, 2017, 2018) and in any of the zones (East and West). [I have 3 years worth of transactions for the two zones: East and West.]

My objective is to analyze how much revenue is earned, how many quantities are sold, and how many transactions occurred for each combination of these products in a given year for a given zone.

I was able to do the above operation (using `purrr::map`) by splitting the data based on zones. I have created a list of two data frames that hold data grouped by "year" for each combination described above. This works well. However, the code is a little clunky in my opinion. There are a lot of repetitive statements. I want to be able to  create a list of 2X3 (i.e. 2 zones and 3 years)

Here's my code using zone-wise splitting.

**First Try**

```
UZone <- unique(Input_File$Zone)
FYear <- unique(Input_File$Fiscal.Year)

  #Split based on zone
  a<-purrr::map(UZone, ~ dplyr::filter(Input_File, Zone == .)) %>%

  #Create combinations of products
  purrr::map(~mutate_each(.,funs(Exists = . > 0), L.Rev:I.Qty )) %>% 

  #group by Fiscal Year
  purrr::map(~group_by_(.,.dots = c("Fiscal.Year", grep("Exists", names(.), value = TRUE)))) %>% 

  #Summarize, delete unwanted columns and rename the "number of transactions" column
  purrr::map(~summarise_each(., funs(sum(., na.rm = TRUE), count = n()), L.Rev:I.Qty)) %>%
    purrr::map(~select(., Fiscal.Year:L.Rev_count)) %>%
    purrr::map(~plyr::rename(.,c("L.Rev_count" = "No.Trans")))

  #Now do Zone and Year-wise splitting : Try 1
  EastList<-a[[1]]
  EastList <- EastList %>% split(.$Fiscal.Year) 

  WestList<-a[[2]]
  WestList <- WestList %>% split(.$Fiscal.Year) 
  write.xlsx(EastList , file = "East.xlsx",row.names = FALSE)
  write.xlsx(WestList , file = "West.xlsx",row.names = FALSE)
```

As you can see, the above code is very clunky. With limited knowledge of R, I researched https://blog.rstudio.org/2016/01/06/purrr-0-2-0/ and read `purrr::map2()` manual but I couldn't find too many examples. After reading the solution at [How to add list of vector to list of data.frame objects as new slot by parallel?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38508843/how-to-add-list-of-vector-to-list-of-data-frame-objects-as-new-slot-by-parallel/38508984#38508984), I am assuming that I could use X = zone and Y= Fiscal Year to do what I have done above.

Here's what I tried:
**Second Try**

```
  #Now try Zone and Year-wise splitting : Try 2
  purrr::map2(UZone,FYear, ~ dplyr::filter(Input_File, Zone == ., Fiscal.Year == .))
```

But this code doesn't work. I get an error message that : 
`Error: .x (2) and .y (3) are different lengths`

**Question 1:** Can I use `map2` to do what I am trying to do? If not, is there any other better way?

**Question 2:** Just in case, we are able to use `map2`, how can I generate two Excel files using one command? As you can see above, I have two function calls above. I'd want to have only one.

**Question 3:** Instead of two statements below, is there any way to do sum and count in one statement? I am looking for more cleaner ways to do sum and count.

```
purrr::map(~summarise_each(., funs(sum(., na.rm = TRUE), count = n()), L.Rev:I.Qty)) %>%
    purrr::map(~select(., Fiscal.Year:L.Rev_count)) %>%
```

Can someone please help me?

---

Here's my data:

```
dput(Input_File)

structure(list(Zone = c("East", "East", "East", "East", "East", 
"East", "East", "West", "West", "West", "West", "West", "West", 
"West"), Fiscal.Year = c(2016, 2016, 2016, 2016, 2016, 2016, 
2017, 2016, 2016, 2016, 2017, 2017, 2018, 2018), Transaction.ID = c(132, 
133, 134, 135, 136, 137, 171, 171, 172, 173, 175, 176, 177, 178
), L.Rev = c(3, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 2, 1, 1, 2, 2, 1, 2, 1), L.Qty = c(3, 
0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 1, 2, 1), A.Rev = c(0, 0, 0, 1, 
1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0), A.Qty = c(0, 0, 0, 2, 2, 3, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 3, 0, 0), I.Rev = c(4, 4, 4, 0, 1, 0, 3, 0, 0, 0, 
1, 0, 1, 1), I.Qty = c(2, 2, 2, 0, 1, 0, 3, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 
1)), .Names = c("Zone", "Fiscal.Year", "Transaction.ID", "L.Rev", 
"L.Qty", "A.Rev", "A.Qty", "I.Rev", "I.Qty"), row.names = c(NA, 
14L), class = "data.frame")
```

---

Output Format:
Here's the code to generate the output. I would love to see `EastList.2016` and `EastList.2017` as two sheets in one Excel file, and `WestList.2016`, `WestList.2017` and `WestList.2018` as 3 sheets in one Excel file.

```
  #generate the output:
  EastList.2016 <- EastList[[1]]
  EastList.2017 <- EastList[[2]]
  WestList.2016 <- WestList[[1]]
  WestList.2017 <- WestList[[2]]
  WestList.2018 <- WestList[[3]]
```

Comment: First use `dplyr` without `purrr`; you can do most of what you're attempting just with grouping. Also check out `tidyr`, which will let you easily reshape your data from wide to a tidier long format without variables stored in the column labels. You'll also find tidy data is also easier to manipulate.

Comment: @alistaire - Thanks. Do you mind posting a solution? I have spent about 6 hours on this code. I am not sure I am following your logic...

Comment: What is the exact desired output? There's tons of stuff in the final `a` object, what do you really want from it?

Comment: I'd start with `Input_File %>% gather(var, val, -1:-3) %>% group_by(Zone, Fiscal.Year, var) %>% mutate(exists = val > 0)`

Comment: @Fr - Thanks for your question. The desired output are EastList and WestList (two separate files broken down by years)...

Comment: @alistaire - Thanks for your comment. I tried your approach, but I don't know how to iterate over zone and then year...Maybe I am new to R programming that's why I am not following your thought. I'd appreciate if you could help me. The sample output could be generated from my code --i.e. WestFile and EastFile...

Comment: @watchtower … and what columns, with what values in them?

Comment: @ watchtower - would it be possible to post up what exactly you would like your final analysis to look like? Two separate 'Files' broken down by years but grouped by zone? Tidy data precepts would push you in the direction of leaving all your data in a single dataframe...  In any case, debeugging is much easier if we can compare outputs of our developing approaches to exactly what you are looking for.

Comment: @Fr - Thanks for your question. EastList has two years 2016 and 2017. So, I would have the same columns as EastList has except the fiscal year 2016 and 2017. i.e. There would be two dataframes--EastList.2016 and EastList.2017, each having the same columns as EastList without the Fiscal year column. Similarly, the code should generate WestList.2016, WestList.2017, and West.2018---3 dataframes for each year, with same columns as WestList minus Fiscal Year column. Does that help? If it does, I will add all these comments to the questions for clarity.

Comment: @leerssej - You are correct. I have added the output format for clarity.

Comment: to follow up on Alistaire's suggestion - I've found this paper to be a great introduction to the subject. http://vita.had.co.nz/papers/tidy-data.pdf

Answer (score 0):

Two lists broken down by year with sums and counts for each?

In *dplyr*:
(df <- your dataframe)

```
df %>% 
group_by(Zone, Fiscal.Year) %>%
summarise_at(vars(L.Rev:I.Qty), funs(sum = sum, cnt = n()))

Source: local data frame [5 x 14]
Groups: Zone [?]

   Zone Fiscal.Year L.Rev_sum L.Qty_sum A.Rev_sum A.Qty_sum I.Rev_sum I.Qty_sum L.Rev_cnt L.Qty_cnt A.Rev_cnt A.Qty_cnt I.Rev_cnt I.Qty_cnt
  <chr>       <dbl>     <dbl>     <dbl>     <dbl>     <dbl>     <dbl>     <dbl>     <int>     <int>     <int>     <int>     <int>     <int>
1  East        2016         4         4         3         7        13         7         6         6         6         6         6         6
2  East        2017         2         1         0         0         3         3         1         1         1         1         1         1
3  West        2016         4         4         0         0         0         0         3         3         3         3         3         3
4  West        2017         3         3         1         3         1         1         2         2         2         2         2         2
5  West        2018         3         3         0         0         2         2         2         2         2         2         2         2
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. Your output is not quite what I am looking for because the rows ("the combinations") have been added. I have added the output at your request.

Comment: @watchtower - thanks for adding in the desired endgoal. Looking at that, I do have to ask if you *really* want to chop up your data like that. I am currently envisioning a boardroom where 5 people flip back and forth between each of those sheets trying to see a pattern in the data: a la http://giphy.com/gifs/punch-blake-flipbook-h6ie9ZuRFaapG. I think the best thing I can recommend here is Tableau or Qliksense - or you can go for the gold and get your Shiny on...